# Database synchronisation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, synchronization

I have a question with regards to synchronizing 2 DB on a daily basis, but first let me share some context.

Technical environment:

- Windows Server 2012R2 Standard edition
- SQL Server 2012

**Functional environment**: the main database is a production database. It is populated every morning using informatica with a full export from a partner data base (FYI no way to modify the latest).

When my production is populated then I create a dump and populate another database for data sciences/BI/... to play with (first the BI DB is purged).

When BI database is populated, there is no synchronization required between production & BI during the day. Both database live completely unconnected during the day.

In the current situation, the BI team is able to connect at its database by mid day (due to the volumes ~ 500 G every day) - this is not acceptable

So now we have some context, how could I make sure the BI database is ready for use as soon as the production database is populated.

Any idea is most welcome so feel free

Comment: How long does it take to take a compressed full backup and restore it on the other server?

Comment: Hi, it takes 4 hours daily give and take

Comment: Are the databases on the same server?

Comment: No - 2 different machines

Comment: What is the storage solution and does it support disk snapshots?

Comment: Production is on the full fledge production server (VM) while the other is on another server (another VM)

Comment: I believe the VM use netApp but I was wondering if the solution could not be on the Informatica side ???

Comment: I was thinking about this too while exchanging with you but not sure which option is the “best” in class

Answer (score 1):

Your options AFAIK

1) Dual-Load both databases from the ETL tool.

2) Use a disk snapshot or a VM snapshot.

3) Put the production database in Full recovery mode and use [Log Shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks David very much appreciate: I discarded the log shipping as the BI dB must not be kept in sync after being created (just so you have the full picture)

Comment: Additional question: any idea how difficult is to clone an etl process

Comment: It's typically simple to clone an ETL process, but it can create additional load on the data source and ETL system.  And with log shipping you could recreate the BI DB every day, and at the end of the load recover the database and make it writable.